# Rotate Icon 360 degrees clockwise angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rotation

Angular newbie here, I am trying to create a button that will have an icon inside of it rotate 360 degrees once click on. As of now I have the rotate but it rotates the whole button instead of just the element. Looking to just have it rotate the "blue square" when the button is clicked. (And yes I understand as of now I am only having the button itself rotate due to ng-click being on the button and nothing on the div.box)

HTML Code:

```
<button ng-controller="fullRotation" ng-click="fullRotate()">Rotate
     <div class="box"></div>
</button>
```

NG Code

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var fullRotation = function ($scope, $element) {
     var degrees = 360;
     $element.css('transition', '-webkit-transform 800ms ease');

     $scope.fullRotate = function() {
          $element.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
          degrees += 360;
     };
}
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWksXCI7SWj0nvr1xD25?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only blue box rotate when you click blue box

```
 <button >Rotate

    <div class="box" ng-controller="fullRotation" ng-click="fullRotate()"></div>

  </button>
```

> Only blue box rotate when you click button

```
  $scope.fullRotate = function() {
    console.log('im here');
    $element.children().css('transition', 'transform 800ms ease');
    $element.children().css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    degrees += 360;
  };
```

> other way is to add transition to button css

```
/* Styles go here */
.box{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: skyblue;
    margin: 50px;
    display: block;
    transition: 800ms ease;
}


 $scope.fullRotate = function() {
    $element.children().css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    degrees += 360;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but not what I was looking for. I want the box to rotate if the button itself is clicked not click on the blue box and it will rotate.

Comment: @user1431083 check edited answer. It works on all latest browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the update, not sure why I didn't think leaving the transition call on the box already. Thanks for the smart thinking.

Answer (score 1):

It was the simple answer of a parent looking for their child.

For anyone looking for this answer in the future I moved all .css() into the fullRotate function and added children()

```
$scope.fullRotate = function() {
     console.log('im here');
     $element.children().css('transition', '-webkit-transform 800ms ease');
     $element.children().css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
     degrees += 360;
```

};

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cm5LhZOF7erZ6NdFvQAP?p=preview) Chrome only